# WMI query is halting

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, wmi-query

When I run this command in powershell, I get no response. I have to kill powershell because I cannot cancel the query once it is made.

```
Get-WMIObject -query 'SELECT * from Win32_UserAccount'
```

What steps could be taken to see why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Querying Active Directory is the preferred method for retrieving domain user accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most commands I'd suggest adding `-Verbose`, but I don't think `Get-WMIObject` outputs much useful info on that stream.

As to why it's hanging, keep in mind that that command will enumerate *every* user account on your domain (not just the local machine). If you're running this on a large network, it will take some time. Even my small network of ~800 user objects take 15 seconds to run.

If you're on a big network... let it run, it'll probably take a while.

The [guidance from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507(v=vs.85).aspx) regarding this class is:

> **Note**  Because both the **Name** and **Domain** are key properties, enumerating **Win32_UserAccount** on a large network can negatively affect performance. Calling **GetObject** or querying for a specific instance has less impact.

It's still going to take a long time to run, but the CIM version of this is a touch faster (12.5 seconds instead of 15 in my case):

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserAccount
```

or, if you want to stick with the query format:

```
Get-CimInstance -Query 'SELECT * from Win32_UserAccount'
```

Comment: Indeed, the command is able to execute quickly when my machine is in airplane mode. It must be the large network is the reason why I am unable to run when connected to the network. Thanks!